# Tail -f - Show last X lines that match a pattern

Tags: grep, match, tail

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of `tail -f -n10` for a matched pattern.

At first I thought `tail -f -n10 | grep PATTERN` but that only returns lines that match the pattern in the last 10 lines of the file.

What I'm looking for is the last ten matches that exist in the file, not the matches in the last ten lines of the file. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Please note:** I specified tail -f because I would like the output to be continuous. I'm using this command to watch a log file for a specific pattern.

Comment: +1 for tricky problem. Would love to see solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`grep PATTERN FILE | tail -n10; tail -f -n0 FILE | grep PATTERN;`

Comment: I didn't think of doing it in two separate commands. This works perfectly!

Comment: New lines could be written in between the commands that you wouldn't pick up.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
tail -f FILE | grep PATTERN | tail -f -n10
```